# How to store cache per user session in PHP?

Tags: php, session, caching

I wanted to cache my PHP output. I am just interested in simple PHP solution. No Memcache/Redis/APC for now. Currently I am doing like this,

```
<?php

$timeout = 3600; // One Hour
$file = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (file_exists($file) && (filemtime($file) + $timeout) > time()) {
    // Output the existing file to the user
    readfile($file);
    exit();
} else {
    // Setup saving and let the page execute
    ob_start();

    // HTML Output

    $content = ob_get_flush();
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
}

?>
```

It is working fine.

But, what if we have logged in user information on this page. Any further requests will get data from this file & it may contain that logged in user's information. How to deal with this?

Do we have to create cache files per session/user?

Comment: You don't usually cache dynamic personalized resources  like this for exactly this reason. Inside a login area, it's much better to use selective caching where applicable (like with big lists or queries that take very long).

Comment: You should really explain why you don't want to use the industry standard solutions to such problems.  If this is a learning project, say so.

Comment: Yes it is not recommended to use cache for pages where user data resides, we can use it for large static content like js,images etc

Answer (score 2):

If you have some specific reason for caching the output of a page per-user, consider caching the data that this paged is based on.  That is, make an application layer cache rather than doing it at the web server or output stage.  Otherwise, don't worry about it... set the appropriate headers and let the browser worry about caching.  You're creating more of a problem by trying to re-invent the wheel here when you have a page that is being generated for only a single user anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code - cache per user session.

```
$timeout = 3600; // One Hour

$_uuid = isset($_SESSION['uuid']) ? $_SESSION['uuid'] : uniqid() . "_" .time();
$_SESSION['uuid'] = $_uuid;

$file = $_uuid . "_" . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (file_exists($file) && (filemtime($file) + $timeout) > time()) {
    // Output the existing file to the user
    readfile($file);
    exit();
} else {
    // Setup saving and let the page execute
    ob_start();

    // HTML Output

    $content = ob_get_flush();
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
}

?>
```